# Continuously differentiable function whose Jacobian has an everywhere singular square submatrix is not injective?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

My question arises from exercise 2-37 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, which asks the following:

> (a) Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that $f$ is $not\mbox{ 1-1}$. $Hint:$  If, for example, $D_1f(x,y)\neq0$ for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $A$, then consider $g:A\to\mathbb{R^2}$ defined by $g(x,y) = (f(x,y),y)$.
>
> (b) Generalize this result to the case of a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ with $m<n$.

First I want to provide a little bit of context. (In case anyone in the future also needs help with his problem).
I managed to solve (a) and a part of b. Specifically, the book provides a hint in which you define a function $g: \mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^n}$, defined by $g(x)=(f(x),x_{m+1},...,x_{n})$, where $x=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$. Then, by assuming there is some point $a$ in which $Dg(a)=0$, one can use the inverse function theorem to claim the existence of an open set jn which the function is not injective.
My following attempt at a proof follows from the remaining case in which $Dg(a)$ is not invertible for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$. The derivative $Dg(a)$ has this form
$$Dg(a) = \left[
          \begin{array}{cc}
             D_{1,\ldots,m} f(x) &  D_{m+1,\ldots,n} f(x) \\
             0        & I    
          \end{array}
        \right]$$
where $D_{1,\ldots,m} f(x)$ are the first m columns of $Df(x)$, $0$ denotes the $(n-m)$x$(m)$ null matrix, and $I$ the $(n-m)$x$(n-m)$ identity matrix. Then, Dg(a) is singular if and only if $D_{1,\ldots,m} f(x)$ is singular, which prompts the proposition in the title of this question. Here is my attempt:
Keeping the above hypothesis, for convenience say $D:= D_{1,\ldots,m} f(x)$. We know $D$ has zero determinant for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, let's fix $x$. D has $0$ as one of its eigenvalues, which means there is a non-zero point $(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})$ in $\mathbb{R^m}$ such that $D \cdot (h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})=0$. We define $h=(h_{1},...,h_{m},0,\ldots,0)$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Then, since $D \cdot (h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})=0$, the function is constant with respect to the first $m$ coordinates, it follows by our definition of $h$ that $f(x+h)=f(x)$, thus $f$ is not injective.

I would appreciate it if someone could verify this and point out any mistakes. I feel like I was a little hand-wavy in the end there. Also if this is absolutely incorrect maybe nudge me in the right direction. While searching I saw a lot of answers that made use of the Constant Rank Theorem which I haven't covered yet, so I tried to come up with something else. Thanks a lot for reading!

Edit: The idea that I'm trying to convey is that given x, there is some vector h by which you can nudge x that results in no changes in f. Not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: I'm not the most knowledgeable in multidimensional calculus, but in one dimension a derivative of $0$ does not imply it is not injective in some neighborhood of that point. Look at $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: You are right. I think non-injectivity follows from there being a neighbourhood where the derivative is exactly 0, which I'm not sure if I'm using correctly. The idea that I'm trying to convey is that given $x$, there is some vector $h$ by which you can nudge $x$ that results in no changes in $f$. Thanks for your reply, I'll keep thinking about it.